# Cropping image in Android using opencv

Tags: android, image-processing, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.3.1 in Android. I need to crop the image into half.
What I am doing is:

```
    Mat mIntermediateMat2 = new Mat(frame_height,frame_width,rgba.type);
    mIntermediateMat2 = rgba.clone();
    mIntermediateMat2 = mIntermediateMat2.rowRange(0,frame_height/2);
```

Will the third step do the job or I have to add something more?
I saw Mat::operator() in opencv 2.3 documentation but unfortunately not able to find in the opencv Android package.

Comment: Have you tried doing it the way you proposed above and it didn't work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are a few constructors for the Mat class, one of which takes a Mat and an ROI (region of interest).

Here's how to do it in Android/Java:

```
Mat uncropped = getUncroppedImage();
Rect roi = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
Mat cropped = new Mat(uncropped, roi);
```

Comment: just to clarify the roi . x,y is the start location of the rectangle you want to set as roi, and width - height is the width - height of the rectangle. it isn't the image width - height. so for example if you have a 320*240 picture, and want to split that image in 2 new images. the first roi will be  Rect roi = new Rect(0, 0, width/2, height);  the second Rect roi = new Rect(160, 0, width/2, height);

Comment: idk why but this logic giving me exception

Answer (score 2):

I have always done cropping this way:

```
Mat image = ...; // fill it however you want to
Mat crop(image, Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows / 2)); // NOTE: this will only give you a reference to the ROI of the original data

// if you want a copy of the crop do this:
Mat output = crop.clone();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I use Mat crop for feature detection without clone it to output. will the opencv look for features in the crop part or in the complete image?

Answer (score 0):

Seems [cv::getRectSubPix](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=getrectsubpix#void%20getRectSubPix%28InputArray%20image,%20Size%20patchSize,%20Point2f%20center,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20patchType%29) does what you want.  Plus you don't have to allocate more space than you need.  Also it does necessary interpolations if the cropped area is not aligned over an exact pixel.

This should do what you want.  Input type will be the output type.

```
Mat dst;
getRectSubPix(src, Size(src.rows()/2,src.cols()), Point2f(src.rows()/4, src.cols()/2), dst);
```