# Cropping image without re-allocating destination object

Tags: android, image, opencv, memory-management

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001993/croping-image-in-android-using-opencv) I took the following code. It crops a region from an original image using OpenCV4Android.

```
Mat uncropped = getUncroppedImage();
Rect roi = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
Mat cropped = new Mat(uncropped, roi);
```

Works fine, but imagine the memory for the Mat that is returned by getUncroppedImage is allocated only once. But the memory for the cropped image is re-allocated all the time. Is there a way to crop a region from OpenCV:Mat without using the Mat-constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Matthias, 'cropped' image in your code points to the same memory as 'uncropped'. No memory is reallocated. To test this you can change content of cropped image (set it to be white for example) and you will see that content of uncropped will be changed as well.

In OpenCV when you want to make two images have same content but different memory you should say so explicitly, i.e. use functions like copy, copyTo or clone. OpenCV tries to avoid memory reallocation and copy whenever possible.

Comment: Right, after reading a bit more into the documentation I realized that they share the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just use a subimage:

```
Mat uncropped = getUncroppedImage();
Rect roi = new Rect(x, y, width, height);

Mat cropped = uncropped(roi);
```

that way, cropped uses the same image array data as uncropped, but only in the subimage area. The **Matrix Header** is created, but the pixel data array (that's what is expensive) isn't.

nearly all openCV functions can work on subimages because theyre just like normal images with another widthstep (byte length of a single row)

**edit**: this i c++ syntax, not sure how android openCV differs!

Comment: Android would be: Mat cropped = uncropped.submat(roi);